# In the web dev framework UIKit, column component, what do the numbers stand for?

Tags: getuikit

Here is the [website](https://getuikit.com/docs/column) of the UIKit documentation for column classes.
They have .uk-column-1-2 to .uk-column-1-6. It makes sense that the 2-6 are the number of columns, but what is the first number? A ratio maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are fractions, that divide space into columns. It's like one sixth of a parent width, two sixths etc.

The same applies to the [width component](https://getuikit.com/docs/width).